# MatInput result is only visible after reloading or refreshing page

Tags: angular, typescript

Below is a matInput it contains value or result but it's only visible after i refresh the page.
[image]

when i select or highlight inside the matInput you can see there is a value or result
[image]

And when i refresh or reload the page the value or result displays correctly
[image]

Source code inside a component's html file

```
 <mat-form-field class="example-full-width">
      <input matInput placeholder="{{this.translate.data['USERNAME'] | translate}}"  
      formControlName="userName" required>
  </mat-form-field>
```

Source Code inside an Angular component:

```
 @Input('user') user!:UserDto;
 userForm!: FormGroup;
 
 ngOnInit(): void {
   this.buildUserForm(this.user); 
 }

 buildUserForm(user: UserDto) {    
   this.userForm = this.formBuilder.group({         
      userName: [user.userName, Validators.required]
   });
 }
```

Comment: I don't understand exactly what the problem is. Is it about the placeholder or the input value ? Can you try to display `this.translate.data['USERNAME']` somewhere ? Depending on how you handle translations, it can end up being empty if you call it too soon

Comment: Also, I don't like having `ngOnInit` and the `@Input()` working concurrently. I would add traces in order to be sure that the `@Input()` is called before `buildUserForm`. You can trace the `@Input` by replacing the attribute with a setter like this : `@Input('user') set user(usrDTO: UserDTO) {console.log('@Input'); this._user = usrDTO}`

Comment: i didn't mention anything like a placeholder and the translations are for a placeholder, i believe you can see the placeholder in all images right! Unless if you haven't worked with matIput ?

Answer (score 0):

There is a design problem in this code. The `FormGroup` is built during the call to `ngOnInit()` and relies on the hypothesis that the `@Input` is already fed, because of this line :

```js
this.userForm = this.formBuilder.group({         
  userName: [user.userName, Validators.required] // What if user is undefined ?
});
```

If `user` is `undefined`, you get a runtime error and the code stops. That would explain why nothing is displayed.

The moment when the `@Input()` is fed depends on the containing component which means that this component **can** be used in a wrong way, which is bad.

Suppose that `user` is fed after an api call, it means that the response will come too late, after the `ngOnInit`.

Here is a proposition for another design. Not the best one but it would solve the problem.

```
/*
 * First, create the FormControl separately.
 * You don't have to, but it will make things easier
 */ 
formControlUserName = new FormControl(undefined, [Validators.required]);

/*
 * Then, create directly the `FormGroup` here, not in a NgOnInit
 * so that you are sure that it is always defined
 */
formGroup = new FormGroup({userName: this.formControlUserName});

/*
 * Then use the setter syntax for the @Input so that it is called
 * whenever the value changes
 */
@Input('user') set user(userDto:UserDto) {
  this.formControlUserName.setValue(userDto.userName);
}
```

Comment: your over thinking . `@Input, getters,..` are always executed before the `ngOnInit()` , meaning you can build you `FormGroup`  inside the `ngOnInit()`  or  `@Input('user') set user(userDto: UserDto){ this.buildUserForm(userDto); }`.  In my case i always have the `@Input` coming with data. I can also change to using a Route Resolver. The problem still stands and i can't figure it out. Could it be a css issue????? ain't sure yet.

Answer (score 0):

"when i select or highlight inside the matInput you can see there is a value or result" - first: check your css: color state for the matInput.

Try this implementation:

```
<mat-form-field class="example-full-width" appearance="fill">
    <mat-label>{{this.translate.data['USERNAME'] | translate}}</mat-label>
      <input matInput formControlName="userName" required>
  </mat-form-field>
```

Comment: Norman i realised i was having a separate css file that was causing the problem and inside it i had `input.mat-input-element { color: transparent; }`

Comment: are you this solved?

Comment: Yup thanks, but  after you had given me a hint that you later edited from your first comment